# How to find 5 shops who sold the most items as well as the total amount of items sold

Tags: sql

`table1` contains the following columns:

- shop_name
- item_name

`table2` contains the following columns:

- item_name
- sold_amount

Comment: When posting a question you should always post your attempt to solve it. Next you should tag on which server you are working, sql is too generic even for this simple task.

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty self explanatory:

```sql
select
  shop_name,
  sum(sold_amount) total_sold
from
  t1 join t2 on t1.item_name = t2.item_name
group by
  item_name
order by
  total_sold desc
limit 5
```